# pdf in python which consist data from .xlsx file and png image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, file-handling, fpdf, reportlab

I wanted to create a pdf using Python 3x.
The pdf should have some text data which is stored in a .xlsx file i.e.., it should read data from .xlsx file and write into the .pdf file.
Along with that, the pdf should have a png image of passport size.

I have come up with two basic ideas which are:-
First one is by writing a program which create a text file in which all required data from the pdf will be written along with the png image. After that the program will convert it into a pdf file.

Second one is by writing a program which will create the pdf file and write the data from .xlsx file as well as insert the image too into the pdf file.

I don't know whether these ideas can be used or not and how it can be used but after going through some researches on GFG, Stack overflow..., I have got totally confused and ended up asking this problem on this platform.

I have tried some modules like PIL, FPDF, reportlab,.. and am successfully able to create a pdf file with either texts or images but unable to combine both in the same text file.
Also I am confused in deciding which idea I should implement.

What I need from you guys is the answer of few of my questions which are:-

1. Are the ideas I mentioned above(second one specially) practically possible?
2. Can I make a program which imports data from file as well as png image into the same pdf. What modules and functions will be used there and how.
   Please provide the code with comments or defining/elaborating the work of function used.

I hope I will get the desired result soon. Meanwhile I will try to solve it out by myself.

Comment: You said you have managed to create pdf with the table, and second one with just the image. You can merge these 2 using  [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) , check ```PdfFileMerger() ``` class

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately I didn't got any notification for this so thought now one have replied. Coming on to the solution, I have used a little bit same. You can check the code [here](https://github.com/meeran2021/Report_Card_Pdf_Generator)